# How can I make a Swift arguments/contents global?

Tags: function, variables, swift

I created this in the Swift Programming Language and I want to know how I can make the shoppingList array global so I can access it from the other function? And how can I make the arguments item1 and item2 global? Here is the code and thanks for the help:

```
func createList(item : String, item2: String){
var shoppingList = [item, item2]
}

createList("apples", "peaches")

func printList(){
println("You need to get \(shoppingList[0]) and \(shoppingList[1]).") //Here is the error
}

printList()
```

Comment: global variable is almost always a bad idea. just return the array and pass it around

Comment: How can I return the array?

Comment: Can you give the code in an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bryan Chen suggested, it is usually not wise to depend on global variables to pass information around.  Bryan suggested that you return the array and pass it around which would look something like this:

```
func createList(item1: String, item2: String) -> [String] {
    let shoppingList = [item1, item2]
    return shoppingList
}

func printList(shoppingList: [String]) {
    if shoppingList.count >= 2 {
        println("You need to get \(shoppingList[0]) and \(shoppingList[1]).")
    } else {
        println("Expected 2 items in shopping list")
    }
}

let list = createList("apples", "peaches")

printList(list)
```

Comment: This really helped and helped me understand how to return an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your variable outside of the function's scope, or make tour function return an array, an pass it back to `printList`.

This is how you return values from functions :

```
func returnSomething() -> String // Returns a string
```

I strongly recommend you to study the [official documentation for Swift language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_245) though.

Comment: I am studying the iBook made by Apple on Swift but I have not reached function and was testing some stuff out but thanks anyways!